# JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed when pulling from mySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, jwt

For context, I'm trying to send a one time link to the user's email as a reset password link that will take them to the reset password page if the jwt token is successfully verified. I followed a tutorial and created a dummy version where user info was stored locally and it worked perfectly. But when I try to implement into my main project which pulls user data from mySQL I keep getting a malformed error, I am checking all the values and everything matches including checking the token on the jwt website to see if it return the correct info which it does so I'm very confused as to what I've done wrong. The only thing that changes between the test and main project is where the data is pulled from. Here is my code for this part of the project:

```
// Create and send link
router.post('/forgot-password', (req, res, next) => {
    var email = req.body.email
    db.query('SELECT * FROM users_test WHERE email = ?', [ email ], (error, results) => {

      if (results.length < 1) {
          res.send('no user')
          return
      }

      const user = results[0]
      const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET + user.password

      const payload = {
          email: email,
          id: user.id
      }

      const token = jwt.sign(payload, secret)
      const link = `http://localhost:5000/auth/reset-password/${user.id}/${token}`
      console.log(link)
      res.send('sent')
  })
})

// verify token and display password reset page
router.get('/reset-password/:id/:token')= (req, res, next) => { 
    const { id, token } = req.params

    db.query('SELECT * FROM users_test WHERE id = ?', [ id ], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        const user = results[0]

        const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET + user.password
        res.json({secret})
        try {
            var payload = jwt.verify(token, secret)
            res.render('reset-password.hbs')
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    })
}
```

The line the error is point at: `var payload = jwt.verify(token, secret)`

The error I'm getting:

```
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^
JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (C:\Users\winba\Desktop\SecureSoftware\Secure-Software-02\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:63:17)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\winba\Desktop\SecureSoftware\Secure-Software-02\controllers\auth.js:497:29)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\winba\Desktop\SecureSoftware\Secure-Software-02\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (C:\Users\winba\Desktop\SecureSoftware\Secure-Software-02\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\winba\Desktop\SecureSoftware\Secure-Software-02\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\winba\Desktop\SecureSoftware\Secure-Software-02\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:149:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (C:\Users\winba\Desktop\SecureSoftware\Secure-Software-02\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:133:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\winba\Desktop\SecureSoftware\Secure-Software-02\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\winba\Desktop\SecureSoftware\Secure-Software-02\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\winba\Desktop\SecureSoftware\Secure-Software-02\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
```

Any help or ideas as to where the error is coming from would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following changes

```
const link = `http://localhost:5000/auth/reset-password/${user.id}/${JSON.stringify(token)}`


var payload = jwt.verify(JSON.parse(token), secret)
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, the stringify puts quotation marks around the token part of the url, which, if i try to go to gives me a unexpected token at 1 in JSON position 0. Unless there is a way to pass it through by removing the quotation marks? This is what the url looked like: http://localhost:5000/auth/reset-password/12/"token"